I am unable to authenticate my account to push images to GCP Artifact Registry despite having access. How can I move forward?
I have two accounts (user account and a service account).

My user account (user123@gmail.com) has 'Owner' Role.
My service account (sa123@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com) has 'Artifact Registry Administrator' Role.

Both of these accounts have their access set in the project that my Artifact Registry repository exists.
Now, the annoying part is, I cannot seem to authenticate Docker to push my locally built image to the Artifact Registry repository even when I used the gcloud CLI credential helper method in the docs.
Here's what in my $HOME/.docker/config.json file.
{
    "auths": {},
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "credHelpers": {
        "asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud"
    },
    "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
}

This is the error message I got.
denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" on resource "projects/project-id/locations/asia-southeast1/repositories/repository-name" (or it may not exist)

Steps I have used to push an image to my repository (Artifact Registry) in my project.
1.      gcloud artifacts repositories create repository-name \
            --repository-format=docker \
            --location=asia-southeast1 \
            --description="DESCRIPTION" \
            --immutable-tags \
            --async


gcloud auth configure-docker asia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev

docker build . --tag IMAGE_URL

docker push IMAGE_URL


I have done these steps locally on my terminal using the two accounts I have above.
Frustratingly, nothing seems to work no matter how I tried.
I also tried gcloud auth login and service account impersonation as well.
However, prior to all my failed attempts, I did manage to push the image ONCE from my terminal. But that's it. It wouldn't seem to work anymore. Can anyone help me please?

Which command do you perform to push your image? Is it a docker push?

@guillaumeblaquiere yes. i used docker push

Can you perform a gcloud auth application-default login and try again? It should work, let me know. If so, I will answer to explain why

i ran ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth application-default login, and saw:
Your browser has been opened to visit: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?res ....
Credentials saved to file: [/Users/localid/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]
These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC)
Quota project "supplier-batterywholesale-com" was added to ADC which can be used by Google client libraries for billing and quota. Note...
i updated Google Cloud CLI components, build image and pushed again. got the same deny msg.

"Unauthenticated request" means that Artifact Registry isn't receiving auth, so something is going wrong on the client side. https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication has detailed info on how to authenticate.
Permissions/roles (other than allUsers) do not matter at this point since there is no auth for Artifact Registry to check
It's impossible to know what's wrong with your setup, but a common pitfall is using sudo for docker push but not for the auth configuration commands. I would also double-check $HOME/.docker/config.json

Hi James, thanks for the answer. I have used the 'gcloud CLI credential helper' method for my authentication. I will add this information and what is inside my $HOME/.docker/config.json file as well in my question. thanks!

Based on the steps that you provided, can you retry pushing again through the service account key method after doing step 4:
cat KEY-FILE | docker login -u KEY-TYPE --password-stdin \
https://LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev


Replace the following:
KEY-TYPE is one of the following:
_json_key if you are using the service account key in JSON format as it was provided when you created the file. _json_key_base64 if you base64-encoded the all contents of the file. KEY-FILE is the name of the service account key file in JSON format. LOCATION is the regional or multi-regional location of the repository where the image is stored.

